# do something if a class is not visible on screen

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if ($('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked') && e.keyCode == 38 && $('.md').not(':visible'))  {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('323');
    }
});
```

Why console is written although some `.md` class is visible on screen ?

Also tried, without success:

```
if ($('.postitle').hasClass('pmarked') && e.keyCode == 38 && $('.md').is(':hidden'))
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.not(':visible')`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) would return a list of elements that are hidden, not a boolean.

You could instead check if the visible items length is 0.

e.g.

```
$('.md:visible').length === 0
```

Comment: `$('.md:visible').length === 0)` - it works, thanks a lot.